# What's the difference between MPO (multi-plane overlay) compositing and DWM compositing?

Tags: direct3d, flip, dwm, dxgi

Can someone explain to me What's the point of MPO and what difference it makes when enabled?

Comment: MPO is a file format. What's the relation with Windows DXGI (DirectX Graphics Infrastructure) and Windows DWM (Desktop Window Manager)?

Comment: MPO stands for multi plane overlay. My question here is about how it effects the presentation process compared to leave it MPO disabled.

Comment: You didn't use the good tag, there's no tag for that.